# Multiplying two variables and inserting total into input JavaScript on.click command

Tags: javascript, input

I have two inputs width and height to calculate the area of a triangle.  When you type number in each input for width and height I then need a submit button to multiply width x height and insert total area into an input.

HTML:

```
<p id="instructions" class="Main">Enter the width and height of your triangle to calculate the area.</p>

<!--Main div-->
<form id="mainform">
       Width (b):
            <input type="Text" id="width" placeholder="width" >
    <div>
        Height(h):
            <input type="text" id="height" placeholder="height">
    </div>
            <button type="button" id="total" onclick="calculateArea()">Calculate Area</button>
                </form>

                <!--Divider-->
                <form>
                    <div id="divider">  
                    </div>
                    <div id="area">
                        The area is: 
                        <input type="text" name="txtarea" id="total">
                    </div>
                </form>     
        </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
    function calculateArea() {
    var width = document.getElementById('width').value; 
    var height = document.getElementById('height').value;
    var total = document.getElementById('total');
    total.value = width * height;
     }
```

Comment: JAVA != JAVASCRIPT

Answer (score 1):

- Both were having same id 'total'. I have named one as 'product'.
- `total.value = myResult;` There was a typo error too.

```js
 function calculateArea() {
   var width = document.getElementById('width').value;
   var height = document.getElementById('height').value;
   var total = document.getElementById('product');
   var myResult = width * height;
   total.value = myResult;
 }
```

```html
<p id="instructions" class="Main">Enter the width and height of your triangle to calculate the area.</p>

<!--Main div-->
<form id="mainform">
  Width (b):
  <input type="Text" id="width" placeholder="width">
  <div>
    Height(h):
    <input type="text" id="height" placeholder="height">
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="total" onclick="calculateArea()">Calculate Area</button>
</form>

<!--Divider-->
<form>
  <div id="divider">
  </div>
  <div id="area">
    The area is:
    <input type="text" name="txtarea" id="product">
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong element with the id "total".
The button shouldn't, the input should.

Answer (score 0):

You should select the element by Id and then assign the result as value to the element

So in your case, it should be:
remove the total as id from the button. Now you have only one element with the unique id 'total'
document.getElementById("txtArea").value = result;

Answer (score 0):

1. You have two elements with `id="total"`. Change the id attribute on your button to something else or remove it.
2. You capitalized `myResult` in the last line of your javascript function. Casing matters in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can write `return myResult`, then the calculateArea function will return myResult.

Also, "id" is used for unique elements - use "class" for multiple elements.